# count each number until they equal with data attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few bars. I want to count them until they are equal with their data-line value. You can see my code below. I used setInterval and when they are equal i want clearInterval but it's not working. I commented this line `percent.html(counter + ' %');` below because its being infinite counter. 
Any help i will be grateful

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var counter = 0;
  var processBar = $('.person-process');
  var percent = $('.person-process-percent .percentage');




  processBar.each(function() {
    var processTop = $(this).data('line');


    var id = setInterval(frameTop, 50);

    function frameTop() {

      if (counter === processTop) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        counter += 1;
        //percent.html(counter + ' %');
      }
    }
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .process-bar {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 265px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
</style>
<div class="person-box">


  <div class="process-bar-wrapper">
    <div class="process-bar">
      <div class="person-process" data-line="34">
        <div class="person-process-percent"><span class="percentage"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>

<div class="person-box">


  <div class="process-bar-wrapper">
    <div class="process-bar">
      <div class="person-process" data-line="60">
        <div class="person-process-percent"><span class="percentage"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>

<div class="person-box">


  <div class="process-bar-wrapper">
    <div class="process-bar">
      <div class="person-process" data-line="80">
        <div class="person-process-percent"><span class="percentage"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var percent = $('.person-process-percent .percentage');

  $('.person-process').each(function() {
    var processTop = parseInt($(this).data('line'));
    var percent = $(this).find('.percentage');
    var counter = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frameTop, 50);

    function frameTop() {

      if (counter === processTop) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        counter++;
        percent.html(counter + ' %');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .process-bar {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 265px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
</style>
<div class="person-box">
  <div class="process-bar-wrapper">
    <div class="process-bar">
      <div class="person-process" data-line="34">
        <div class="person-process-percent"><span class="percentage"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="person-box">
  <div class="process-bar-wrapper">
    <div class="process-bar">
      <div class="person-process" data-line="60">
        <div class="person-process-percent"><span class="percentage"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="person-box">
  <div class="process-bar-wrapper">
    <div class="process-bar">
      <div class="person-process" data-line="80">
        <div class="person-process-percent"><span class="percentage"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```